# Getting items from an MFC list control from .NET

Tags: c#, winapi, mfc, controls

I have a C# application that needs to retrieve a bunch of information from another window that was written in C++ using MFC. The C# app is a plugin to a product containing this other window so they are both running within the same process.

This other window contains a number of fields that I have successfully gotten the strings from by calling:

```
[DllImport( "user32.dll", SetLastError = true )]
        public static extern uint GetDlgItemText( IntPtr hDlg, int nIDDlgItem, [Out] StringBuilder lpString, int nMaxCount );
```

But it also contains 2 list controls that may contain a number of rows of data, each with a number of columns.

How do I fetch this data?

Is there another function in user32.dll I should be using?

Can you get a handle to the list control using:

```
[DllImport( "User32", SetLastError = true )]
        public static extern IntPtr GetDlgItem( IntPtr hwndParent, int ItemId );
```

and then somehow cast it into a .NET control that you can get the rows and columns from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually surprisingly difficult.  The LVM_* messages that you would use to get the data out of the listview controls are considered user-defined messages, and their parameters cannot be marshaled across process boundaries using standard Win32 calls.

There *are* ways to accomplish this -- one is to inject code into the remote process (using, say, CreateRemoteThread) and then have that remote thread perform the operation and write the results into shared memory -- but they are non-trivial and I don't have good example code for you.

Edit:  OK, if you're int the same process you ought to be able to make this work.  Here's some code (pulled from [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542378/embedding-a-file-explorer-instance-in-a-winforms-app-form)) that uses the LVM_* messages to extract the selected text from a list control.  This ought to get you going in the right direction.  There's also an article [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369155/getting-text-from-syslistview32-in-64bit) that has similar code.  He couldn't get it to work due to crossing process boundaries, but it might work for you.

```
private string GetSelectedItem()
{
    string item = null;

    IntPtr pStringBuffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(2048);
    IntPtr pItemBuffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(LVITEM)));

    int selectedItemIndex = SendMessage(base.Handle, LVM_GETNEXTITEM, (IntPtr)(-1), (IntPtr)LVNI_SELECTED).ToInt32();
    if (selectedItemIndex > -1)
    {
        LVITEM lvi = new LVITEM();
        lvi.cchTextMax = 1024;
        lvi.pszText = pStringBuffer;
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(lvi, pItemBuffer, false);
        int numChars = SendMessage(base.Handle, LVM_GETITEMTEXT, (IntPtr)selectedItemIndex, pItemBuffer).ToInt32();
        if (numChars > 0)
        {
            item = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(lvi.pszText, numChars);
        }
    }

    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pStringBuffer);
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pItemBuffer);

    return item;
}

struct LVITEM
{
    public int mask;
    public int iItem;
    public int iSubItem;
    public int state;
    public int stateMask;
    public IntPtr pszText;
    public int cchTextMax;
    public int iImage;
    public IntPtr lParam;
    public int iIndent;
    public int iGroupId;
    int cColumns; // tile view columns
    public IntPtr puColumns;
    public IntPtr piColFmt;
    public int iGroup;

}
```

Comment: I am running within the same process. I have developed a plugin to an existing product. I just don't have any programmatic access to that other window other than to use the Win32 calls I believe. An example of how to use the LVM_* messages if they will work in this case would be much appreciated!